# Not able to display the contents in the drop down

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to develop an app.Here I am trying to cascade drop-down box and list, so that when an option is selected from drop-down the list will display options related to the selection made in the drop-down. Here I am not getting the options in the drop-down as well as in list. so, can anyone explain what has to be done and what is the mistake?

https://plnkr.co/edit/WDxFWFe7hxMsxnzqB2W5

**controller.js :**

```
carService.controller('carBrand',['$scope',function($scope){
//$scope.sample="Inside the cartype ctrl";

 $scope.brandList=[
 {'name':'Benz', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan']},
 {'name':'BMW', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan', 'Van']}
];


$scope.home = function () {
    window.location="#/menu.html";
  };

$scope.addEntry=function(){
  window.location="#/carEdit.html";
};
}]);
```

**html :**

```
<ion-view view-title="Car Type">
  <ion-content ng-contorller="carBrand">
    <h3> Add/Edit the Car Types </h3>
    {{sample}}
    Make:
    <select ng-model="carBrand" ng-options="make for (make,types) in brandList"> 
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
     Type:
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="cartype" ng-repeat="brandType in carBrand" ng-disabled="!carBrand">
    <span>{{brandType}}</span>
    </ion-checkbox><br><br>
    <button ng-click="addEntry()">Edit</button>
    <button ng-click="home()">Back</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Try removing `ng-bind=""` from `select` tag

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: sorry I have corrected it @JBNizet

Comment: @RaviTeja  I already run the code by removing the  ng-bind it still remains to be the same

Comment: @sree are you sure that u added the correct code here? controller is not getting called when I open the plunker you added.

Comment: controller.js and html codes are correct @SuvethanNantha

Comment: I hope someone could help me with this ... I tried my maximum hands on it   but couldn't get the correct output.

Comment: @sree hi did you sort this out?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no not yet still figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
make for (make,types) in brandList
```

that is not the correct syntax. The correct syntax is

```
brand as brand.make for brand in brandList
               ^-- that will be the value displayed in the option: the make of the brand
  ^-- that will go into the ng-model of the select (i.e. in carBrand): the complete brand object
```

.

```
brandType in carBrand
```

That is not correct either. You want ot iterate through the types of the selected brand, so it should be

```
brandType in carBrand.types
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your controller is not properly defined in your context. So I have changed a  little for you. See the below code for your reference.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="testController">
     <ion-view view-title="Car Type">
       <ion-content>
          <h3> Add/Edit the Car Types </h3>
            {{sample}}
            Make:
            <select ng-model="carBrand"> 
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option ng-repeat="brand in brandList" value="{{brand.name}}">{{brand.name}}</option>
           </select>
            Type:
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="cartype" ng-repeat="brandType in carBrand" ng-disabled="!carBrand">
           <span>{{brandType}}</span>
            </ion-checkbox><br><br>
           <button ng-click="addEntry()">Edit</button>
           <button ng-click="home()">Back</button>
       </ion-content>
     </ion-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp", []);

function testController($scope) {


  $scope.sample="Inside the cartype ctrl";

 $scope.brandList=[
 {'name':'Benz', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan']},
 {'name':'BMW', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan', 'Van']}];

}
```

Hope this answer helps you.